# Monitor for class changing on element in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When a class is added to an element, I want to add another class to that element. When a class is removed, I want to remove an element. I'm basically mapping some bootstrap classes to some angular form validation classes but I can't figure out how to fire my code when a class is added/removed from an element (also making sure not to cause some infinite loop of class changing).

Here is what I have thus far for my directive:

```
.directive('mirrorValidationStates', ['$log', function($log) {
  function link(scope,element,attrs) {
    scope.$watch(element.hasClass('someClass'), function(val) {
      var classMap = {
        'popupOn': 'has-error',
        'ng-valid': 'has-success'
      };

      for (var key in classMap) {
        if (element.hasClass(key)) {
          $log.info("setting class " + classMap[key]);
          element.parent().addClass(classMap[key]);
        } else {
          $log.info("removing class " + classMap[key]);
          element.parent().removeClass(classMap[key]);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return {
    link: link
  };
}]);
```

So basically, when `popupOn` is added to an element, I want to add the `has-error` bootstrap class to the parent element. When `popupOn` is removed, I want to remove `has-error`.

What am I missing to make this happen in Angular? Maybe something with ng-class and not use a directive?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/faGTg/1/)

You may want to try this construction to follow class changes:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {return element.attr('class'); }, function(newValue){});
```

Please notice that adding/removing classes insight that watch will cause one additional call of adding class that wont change class attribute value.

But I think the better approach will be using ng-class. For example in a moment you want to add a 'popupOn' class you are setting some scope value ($scope.popup = true) and then specify ng-class for parent and child element like so:

```
<div ng-class={'has-error': (popup==true)}>
    <div id="patient" ng-class={'popupOn': (popup==true)}>test</div>
    <button ng-click="addClass()">addClass</button>
    <button ng-click="removeClass()">removeClass</button>
</div>
```

when you want to remove those classes you just set $scope.popup value to false

[Fiddle with ng-class](http://jsfiddle.net/yChUN/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I fully comprehended that construction to $watch when I was reading the docs last night. Thanks much.

Comment: Take care when using $animated elements. As for angular 1.5 this might not trigger for the animation completed state right away, but only for the 'add'-state.

Comment: **$** scope.$watch   - some people copy and paste!

Comment: @AhmadReza in directives scope injection is position based rather than dependency injection like in controllers. So no need $ sign.

Comment: May as well just check for truthy instead of using `popup == true`

Answer (score -5):

I add/remove the class:

```
  function addClass() {
      var element = angular.element('#nameInput');
      element.addClass('nameClass');
  };

  function removeClass() {
      var element = angular.element('#nameInput');
      element.removeClass('nameClass');
  };
```