# Angular Directives communication for altering attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I two directives which function to select a random background image on pageload.

```
.directive('carousel', function(){
return{
  templateUrl: "../templates/carousel.html",
  restrict: "E",
  controller: function($scope, $route) {
    $scope.imageLevel = 1;
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));
      $scope.imageLevel = random;
      console.log(random);
      });
    }

 }            
})

.directive('stateDisplay', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      var parms = attrs['stateDisplay'].split(' ');
      var linkVar = parms[0];
      var classes = parms.slice(1);
      scope.$watch(linkVar, function(newVal) {
          el.removeClass(classes.join(' '));
          el.addClass(classes[newVal]);
      });  
    }
  }

});
```

Carousel.html

```
<article class="fullheight" state-display="imageLevel image1 image2 image3 image4">            


</article>
```

These are functioning well together. I would like to add an attribute directive to offset the image background based on the scroll position. I have an attribute in place, but am not sure how to get a handle of the css attribute that is selected at random and appended to the dom.

Here is what I have so far:

```
app.directive('scrollPosition', function($window) {
return {
    scope: {
      scroll: '=scrollPosition'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.scroll = 0;
},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var windowEl = angular.element($window);
      var handler = function() {
        scope.scroll = windowEl.scrollTop();
        console.log(element[0].attrs);
      }
      windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
      handler();
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<article class="fullheight" scroll-position="scroll" state-display="imageLevel image1 image2 image3 image4">
```

HTML when compiled:

```
<carousel class="ng-isolate-scope">
<article  scroll-position="scroll" class="fullheight ng-isolate-scope image2" state-display="imageLevel image1 image2 image3 image4">
</artice>
</carousel>
```

I'd like to get a hold of the "image2" css class, or whatever style is randomly placed there and adjust that classes css in the handler function. What would be the best method to get a hold of that randomly selected class?

```
console.log(attrs.class);
```

currently only returns "fullheight"

Comment: Using element[0] unwraps the jquery/jqlite element so it no longer has access to the attr method.  You should be able to use element.attr('class')

Comment: I just made an edit to the post.

Comment: Relevant [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693064/monitor-for-class-changing-on-element-in-angularjs-directive)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out: here's the final code...

```
app.directive('scrollPosition', function($window) {


return {
    scope: {
      scroll: '=scrollPosition'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.scroll = 0;
},
  compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {  
    return{
    post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var windowEl = angular.element($window);

  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var handler = function() {
    scope.scroll = windowEl.scrollTop()/5;
    var myObject = attrs.$$element[0].classList[2];
    console.log(scope.scroll + " " + lastScrollTop);

    if(scope.scroll > lastScrollTop){
    $('.fullheight.' + myObject).css({backgroundPositionY:"+" + scope.scroll +"px"});
    }else{
    $('.fullheight.' + myObject).css({backgroundPositionY:"+" + scope.scroll + "px"});
    }
    lastScrollTop = scope.scroll;
  }
  windowEl.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
  handler();
}
}


}
  };
});
```