# Strange behavior when monitoring a class on an Angular directive from inside that directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to monitor whether a particular class is currently on an element with my Angular directive.  Toggling the $scope variable that adds or removes that class would then trigger the directive to update a few things.

What I'm seeing, though, is that the first toggle doesn't take, but then subsequent ones do.  The updates therefore get out of sync.  Here's a simplified example that uses the solution from [Monitor for class changing on element in AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693064/monitor-for-class-changing-on-element-in-angularjs-directive).  What's going on here, and how can I get the class change to stay in sync inside the directive?  Many thanks!

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/scottmcd/pen/rVpmdY)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="compact" /> Compactify
  </label>
  <div>Compactify is set to: {{compact}}</div>
  <div firefly class="crewList" ng-class="{compact: compact}"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.compact = false;
}]);

app.directive('firefly', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<ul ng-class="{compact: compacted}"><li>Capt. Mal</li><li>Zoe</li><li>Wash</li><li>Kaylee</li><li>Book</li><li>Inara</li><li>Jayne</li><li>Simon</li><li>Spoilers, sweetie!</li></ul>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.insideCompactor = function() {
        scope.compacted = element.hasClass('compact');
      };
      scope.insideCompactor();
      scope.$watch(function() {return element.attr('class');}, function(newValue) {
        scope.insideCompactor();
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

CSS:

```
.crewList {font-size: 2rem;}
.crewList UL.compact {font-size: 1rem;}
```

***UPDATE***
While I haven't figured out how to make this work, I did figure out a little more about the problem.  As part of the digest cycle, the $watch inside the directive seems to be firing **before** the class is actually applied to the element itself.  Therefore, the directive's scope variable gets out of sync with what's actually on the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvzEZJ)

You could try just passing the model value to the directive. I removed the `ng-class` directive and replaced it with the `class-model` attribute to pass the data to the directive.

```
<div firefly class="crewList" class-model="compact"></div>
```

Then that value can be referenced in the directive's scope and can be watched directly instead of checking if the element has the class.

```
app.directive('firefly', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<ul ng-class="{compact: compacted}"><li>Capt. Mal</li><li>Zoe</li><li>Wash</li><li>Kaylee</li><li>Book</li><li>Inara</li><li>Jayne</li><li>Simon</li><li>Spoilers, sweetie!</li></ul>',
    scope: {
      classModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.insideCompactor = function() {
        scope.compacted = scope.classModel;
      };
      scope.insideCompactor();
      scope.$watch('classModel', function(newValue) {
        scope.insideCompactor();
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I see.  Because the value is on the isolate scope, you can $watch() it directly rather than trying watch a function that returns the current class list.  That does what I need it to, though I'd still like a way to watch something as common as classes on an element.  Thanks!